# node cron vs node schedule when creating a heroku server to log statistics

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, cron, scheduler

I am attempting to create a Heroku server that logs a different statistic every day from 6 AM to 5 PM and then displays that data collected throughout the day at midnight in the form of an array on the server output.  How do I go about doing this?  In order to create events that fire at the top of the hour each hour every day and store that data, should I use node cron or node schedule?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run some specific code on Heroku at specific time intervals, you should use the [Heroku Scheduler addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler). This is a free addon Heroku provides which does exactly what you want to do, but in a far more reliable way than using JS directly.

The reason this is better is because when you're running code on Heroku, your web server (dyno) will restart from time to time, messing up your scheduled runs if you're keeping state persistent in the Node process.

Comment: Do you know where I could find an implementation of this with javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by an implementation of this? It's a stand-alone service =) You basically write any node JS code, like blah.js, and tell the Heroku scheduler addon to run that Javascript code every hour.